App Crash com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15
I encountered below problem.

Problem:
App Crash  com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xxx.yyy Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Below is the old gradle file format and I used it in android Girafe
build.gradle (Project)
buildscript {

ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'

 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }


 dependencies {

  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0"
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
 }
}

Module Gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


dependencies {

 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'

 }


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I had searched in internet. It seems there is nothing for 2024. I tried downgrade lower version, but it was not working.


are you already call this command inside your method onCreate in main activity?
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}

The last versions of google-services is classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' make sure that your apps depedencies always up-to-date

Had upgraded to com.google.gms:google-services: 4.4.2 BUT NOT working. I didnot use FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) on  pages that needs firebase. Some suggested dont use this approach of FirebaseApp.initializeApp()

I think the changes I made kinda solve the problem just in case others are having the similiar problem. I upgraded the firebase to (1) com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1 (2)still can use com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15 (3)delete the app that deployed to Android phone (4) Clean up and rebuild and deploy to android phone.  Thanks
